# Shared bytes in PLC addresses

Tags: plc

What are the side effects of having two words with one byte shared between them? For example in TIA Portal, if I have IW1 which consists of byte 1 & 2 and IW2 which consists of byte 2 & 3. If I assigned a different value for each of them it worked, so I don't understand when this could be wrong?

Comment: the effect is that you have two words that share a byte

Comment: The problem is in the program everything is working ok ,even when I monitor their values  one is  same as the set point but the other is not , but in simulation they both  behave like the set point

Answer (score 0):

If the value written in one of the variables changes a bit of the shared byte, the value in the other variable will change too, for example:

If you write decimal value 6538 in variable IW1 (6538 = 0001.1001.1000.1010) and then write decimal value 6538 in IW2 (6538 = 0001.1001.1000.1010) the byte 2 (shared) will change value, and the final result for IW1 will be 0001.1001.0001.1001 = 6425 and no longer 6538.

|  |  | byte 1 | byte 2 (shared) | byte 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Write 6538 to IW1 | **0001.1001** | **1000.1010** | 0000.0000 |
| 2 | Write 6538 to IW2 | 0001.1001 | **0001.1001** | **1000.1010** |
| 3 | **New value in IW1 = 6425** | **> 0001.1001** | **0001.1001 <** | 1000.1010 |

You will only not see the change if coincidentally the new value assigned does not change the value of byte 2.

I don't know your application or Siemens in depth, but I strongly recommend avoiding this, as it can generate bugs that are extremely difficult to track down in the future.